# Is there an equivalent of the python 'if name == __main__.py' command in latex?

Tags: include, preamble, multiple-files

I'm busy working on a multi-document latex file. I use \include to import my different chapters into my main file, and I've defined my preamble in a separate .sty file, that I import into my main file using \usepackage.

I'd like to be able to test out different preambles on my different chapters, but because of the way I import the chapters, I can't have individual preambles for each chapter.

In python, when you have multiple modules, you can test-run each module individually using the 'if name == __main__.py' command. Is there a similar thing in latex that would allow you to define preamble's in each chapter that would only get picked up when compiling that chapter by itself, and would get ignored when compiling the chapter from the main file?

Comment: your included files can for example say `\makeatletter\ifnum\@auxout=\@partaux \else \imput{my preamble}\fi`  so it does nothing if \included'ed but inputs a top level preamble if used at top level (but why not use `\includeonly` ?)

Comment: I'm trying to combine different files with clashing preambles. The 'standalone' package looks like it will allow me to have different preambles for each file, but I'd also like to be able have the option of compiling all chapters with the same preamble from my main file, without having to remove all the preambles from the included files.

Comment: oh ok so as I wrote above but instead of `\input{my preambl}` you can literally add the preamble at that point (and a similar test at the end to hide end{document}

Comment: but simpler is to have a separate wrapper file your chapter files can start \chapter{zzz} and have no preamble, your main.tex can \import them all but to process chapter 2 with a different preamble have a chap2-main.tex with its own preamble that just `\input{chapter2.tex}`

Comment: Ok great thanks that makes sense.

Comment: Your idea of using a separate wrapper file I mean. Definitely simplifies things.